# Usage of Global property in Pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2

I want to use a global variable that I have created in my Jenkins Configuration as follow:

[image]

My question is: How can I use it in my Pipeline(aka workflow) job? I'm doing something like:

[image]

When I ran it, It displayed:

```
[Pipeline] node
Running on master in /opt/devops/jenkins_home/jobs/siman/jobs/java/jobs/demo-job/workspace
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: PRODUCTION_MAILS for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:224)
```

Instead If I create a "Free Style Project" I can use the global property as follow without problems:

[image]

When I ran it, it display the value if I do some "echo" as follow:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I achieved it:

```
node('master') {
    echo "${env.PRODUCTION_MAILS}"
}
```

Comment: seems like "global" means Master node only? That seems a bit wonky.

Answer (score -2):

Or You could use

```
echo "This is the value: " + PRODUCTION_MAILS
```

That should work.